# Code Signing error,iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, code-signing

I have been really sick and tired of this. I have done all the possible way to resolve this. But not getting the success. My SWIFT code is working fine on simulator . But when I try to run it on device or try to make an archive , I get this compilation error

```
 Couldn't codesign /Users/SandeepHoney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocialCircle-advannpwpzlrtleupycqgmvugcst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SocialCircle.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib: codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried to re-generate provisioning profiles. but that thing isn't even working. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778666/code-sign-issue-with-swift-project). But not working..
 Don't know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Same issue also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is because of **Apple WWDRCA**  expired at [Feb 14, 2016](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/).

to resolve this

- go to your **Keychain Access**, and in the menu
- click **View** - - > **Show Expired Certificates**.

> **delete** the expired *Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority* from both the **login** and **System** Keychains.

- under **System** you can see like your certificate is expired

[image]

- Install the renewed certificate from Apple by [downloading](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer) and double click it.

  [image: Your keychain should show like that]
- restart your **xcode**
- **Clean your project** and  **Build**

Comment: Thanks you have just saved one life. I am really gonna die.. But hurray .. I am alive now.. Thanks a ton.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Some days ago, everything was working fine . Suddenly this started But you have just saved me . But how come you figured out this solution? Bro. I really wanna know