# Issue with Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode7

I have a app which works fine while running in device without utilizing "Provisioning Profile" of developer certificate but while trying to create a .ipa file with "Provisioning profile"it fails to create.
It gives the error "Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets". Please check the Image 1 showing this error.

To utilize the profile to install an app for client, We have selected the developer certificate, but it throws an error. Since  Both the certificates (developer and Enterprise) is issued on the name of one person only.Please find the Image 2 and 3 showing the error.

We want to know what exactly the issue behind this.[image]

[image]
  [image: ![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoAla.png]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449584/code-signing-error-ios9 check this

Comment: i think its because you are using development provisioning profile , see my answer if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to archive your app then you have to create iOS Distribution certificate not development certificate and then after create AdHoc or Distribution provisioning profile and then try to archive app again.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**First Check the PMCTests targets**

Click on projects PMCTests check bundle identifier and provisioning profile then check for Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority in keychain

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was having the same issue as this question, So I hope this will fix your problem! Download Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority (WWDR) certificate, re add it to the keychain! and delete previouse one from keychain.

Here is the link to download the certificate :
https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

Answer (score 0):

First of all Check if Apple world wide Developer relations certification authority is expired,follow the below steps & if you already installed it then move to next paragraph.

1. Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer
   and double-click to install to **Keychain**.
2. Select **"View" -> "Show Expired Certificates"** in **Keychain** app.
3. Remove Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority certificates from "login" tab and "System" tab in Keychain app.

**Ensure the new downloaded cert is in both login and system** Default to only system tab will still give error.**

*If everything is correct as per first section*,

1. **Generate AdHoc Distribution provisioning profile**  [image]
2. Download and double click on it.
3. Select that profile on build settings & then try to Archieve, it will work.