# Xcode: Unable Run iOs-App on Device

Tags: iphone, xcode, apple-id

Running my Swift2-App onto iPhone SE failed with this error message:

```
*** error: Couldn't codesign /Users/appdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Intelligent Workout.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Xcode: Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

OSX: El Capitan Version 10.11.6 (15G31)

[image: Code Settings]

[image: Dev-Account]

[image: Keychain Access]

Comment: You may find your answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778666/code-sign-issue-with-swift-project

Comment: paste a screenshot of build settings tab of your target

Comment: also tried to delete mobileprovision file.. no success..  appended picture in thread (think you were interested in code signing)

Comment: What does the build result show - specific frameworks/files which fail to code sign? Can you confirm you have the correct mobileprovision/certificate pair?